# Sending emails from Yii2 and wampserver 2.5

Tags: php, email, wampserver, yii2

I am using Yii2 in conjunction with wampserver 2.5 for my project. What I am trying to do is rather basic: I just need to be able to send emails from my local machine.

I have tried various tutorials and how-to's from across the internet and none have worked so far.  I am trying to use swiftmailer, which is included in Yii2 with smtp.gmail.com.

I would really appreciate if someone using this combination (Yii2 and wampserver 2.5) could help me here.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not replace [reading the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/468/send-mail-using-yiimail-extension/)

Comment: Thank you, but that is for yii 1.1.  As stated in the title and post, this is referring to yii2.

Answer (score 2):

I use xampp server with yii2 and swiftmailer extension.I configured my swiftmailer to use my gmail as smtp to send mails.Following is my code.

In the components's section of your common/main-local.php

```
'mail' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@backend/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => false,//to send mails to real email addresses else will get stored in your mail/runtime folder
        //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
                        ],
    ],
    ],
```

In your Controller

```
    \Yii::$app->mail->compose('your_view', ['params' => $params])
    ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => 'Test Mail'])
    ->setTo('to_email@xx.com')
    ->setSubject('This is a test mail ' )
    ->send();
```

This should work! Hope this will help you!

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  I will try it out.  Did you have to do anything in xampp to get it to work?

Comment: smtp has nothing to do with xampp server, it will use gmail server and access to send email. but you may have to set the security settings low on the gmail account you will be using.